# How do I print tables from an SQLite databse in python?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, printing

So I have a database of information that I would like to print in a nice table format, held as an SQLite db file.

The only print statements I have seen print the information in a confusing manner, not aligning the attributes of different entities, no column headers etc.

Procedure that creates the table:

```
def create_table():
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders ( '    #CREATES TABLE named 'orders':
          'name TEXT, '                             #name
          'type_ TEXT, '                            #type of product
          'location STRING, '                       #location of product
          'amount INTEGER, '                        #'weight' of item, g, kg, ml, cl, l, etc. 
          'wholesale_cost REAL, '                   #wholesale cost
          'tax REAL, '                              #tax %
          'sale_pre_tax REAL, '                     #sale value before tax
          'sale_post_tax REAL, '                    #sale value after tax
          'quantity REAL, '                         #how many sold
          'total_sale_pre_tax REAL, '               #total sales before tax
          'total_sale_post_tax, '                   #total sales after tax
          'total_tax REAL, '                        #total tax in GBP
          'total_wholesale_cost REAL, '             #total wholesale cos
          'profit REAL)')                           #total sale profit
```

And this is the print procedure:

```
def read_from_db():
c.execute ('SELECT * FROM orders ') 
for row in c.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

When I execute this it prints:

> ('NORI', 'DRY', 'SHELVES', '50G', 3.4, 20.0, 4.42, 5.303999999999999,
>   3.0, 13.26, 15.911999999999999, 2.6519999999999992, 10.2, 3.0600000000000005)
>
> ('CURRY SAUCE', 'DRY', 'SHELVES', '500G', 5.65, 25.0,
>   7.345000000000001, 9.18125, 1.0, 7.345000000000001, 9.18125, 1.8362499999999997, 5.65, 1.6950000000000003)
>
> ('SALMON', 'CHILLED', 'FRIDGE', '100G', 1.25, 20.0, 1.625, 1.95, 3.0,
>   4.875, 5.85, 0.9749999999999996, 3.75, 1.125)
>
> ('EDAMAME', 'CHILLED', 'FRIDGE', '100G', 3.0, 19.0, 4.0, 5.0, 3.0,
>   12.0, 15, 3.0, 9.0, 3.0)

Which is the information from my database but is there any way to print this as a table instead?

Comment: Can you show us a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

Adding column names to your rows using `row_factory` is [well documented](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory):

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.Connection('my.db')
con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM tbl')

for row in cur.fetchall():
     # can convert to dict if you want:
     print(dict(row))
```

You could then use `str.rjust` and related functions to print the table, or use a `csv.DictWriter` with `sys.stdout` as the "file":

```
import csv
import sys

wtr = csv.DictWriter(sys.stdout, fieldnames=[i[0] for i in cur.description])
wtr.writeheader()

for row in cur.fetchall():
    wtr.writerow(dict(row))
```

Comment: Added this to my code and its giving me an error: 
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is required.
And when I remove the dict() it just prints as it did before.

Comment: This is working for me (Python 3.4.4). I doubt that's an error in the above code; what line is the error on? It seems you are updating a dictionary somewhere with an object that is not a dictionary. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302248/dictionary-update-sequence-element-0-has-length-3-2-is-required).